# std::is_same different results between compilers

Tags: c++, boolean, rvalue, lvalue, value-categories

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    bool b = true;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(!(!b)), bool>::value << "\n";

    auto bb = (!(!b));
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(bb), bool>::value << "\n";
}
```

The above code has different results using different compilers.
Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something?

- clang 1 1 (https://godbolt.org/z/s43T55rxq)
- msvc 1 1 (https://godbolt.org/z/YnKfKh41q)
- gcc 0 1 (https://godbolt.org/z/91xdfv93c)

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug to me, especially since it only comes up with double negation...in the meantime, you could use std::is_convertible

Comment: GCC thinks `!!b` is an lvalue, so `decltype` reports `bool &`. It even allows `!!b = false;` Looks like an obvious bug, please report this. The same happens with any even number of `!`s.

Answer (score 50):

This is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107065). The problem is that gcc incorrectly treats the expression `!(!b)` as an lvalue instead of rvalue. You can confirm this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zv5En5hjG). As you'll see in the above linked demo, the output gcc gives is `lvalue` instead of `prvalue`.

The bug has been reported as:

[GCC treats rvalue as an lvalue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107065)

Comment: Perhaps it happens as an optimization in a very early pass that eliminates !! as "redundant".

Comment: Not only does `value_category` mis-categorize it, `!(!b) = false;` actually compiles (in a debug build https://godbolt.org/z/Wxx3ds84f to a `mov` store that sets `b=0`, otherwise optimized away).  So that's fun.  It's not just a bug in the categorizing output.  Other compilers of course correctly reject this.  @PabloH: any even number of `!` compiles, any odd number is rejected as not being an lvalue, so yeah, your guess about early elimination is compatible with that experiment.